# How can I programmatically browse folder from file explorer android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am able to browse file explorer to read text file inside my application,this is the code I am using for that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("application/text");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select text"), SELECT_TEXT);
```

But on click-on browse button in my application I want to browse all files in `/sdcard/my-folder/` folder .How can I directly browse from this folder.

Please any one help me to implement that.

Comment: Have a look at [android-filechooser](https://code.google.com/p/android-filechooser/).

Comment: solved already @AbiAndroid?